# Next Auth returns error 400: Bad request, what could be the problem?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I used [Next Auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) in Next.js application and I used [KeycloakProvider](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/keycloak) provider, Next.js application was in k8s.

For protect routes I am using middleware.ts file:

```
export const config: {matcher: string[]} = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api/auth|auth|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)'
  ],
};
```

Locally this works well, however in the production of k8s I get an error: 400: Bad Request. The log does not return anything.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue multiple times.

Nextjs middlewares only supports Edge Runtime. There is no support for Nodejs runtimes yet. [More details](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#runtime).

So, there are two ways you can fix this in my opinion:

1. Migrate to Vercel.
2. Use the client side authorization method using the `useSession` hook ([details](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#client-side)).

```
import { useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Page() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  if (status === "unauthenticated") {
    return <p>Access Denied</p>
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Protected Page</h1>
      <p>You can view this page because you are signed in.</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

I hope it helps.